# Unknown class FBSDKLoginButton in Interface Builder file

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, xcode-storyboard

I am experiencing a very frustrating build issue with my brand new project. I am trying to integrate Facebook iOS SDK, but for some reason I am getting some bizarre errors. When trying to use FBSDKLoginKit to display an `FBSDKLoginButton` on a storyboard view.

The first hint something is wrong is this "error" when I attempt to `#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>` (however it only appears as an error in the editor; it still compiles fine):

"Could not build module FBSDKLoginKit."

Strangely, this "error" went away after fiddling with some of the module-related build settings, even when I set them back to their original values.

Also interestingly, if I explicitly reference the `FBSDKLoginButton` class from my view controller (for example add the button programmatically), then storyboard-based instantiation works fine. So I'm guessing this must be some linker issue or something, but I'm admittedly not a pro at that stuff.

None of the Facebook SDK documentation mentions this issue that I can find, which is bizarre because like I said this is a brand new clean project.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My bad, [the documentation *does* mention this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios#login-button), and suggests solving it much as I already figured out, by referencing the `FBSDKLoginButton` class in `application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. (Frankly it doesn't matter where you reference it, so wherever feels most comfortable. For me, the view controller makes more sense.)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [FBSDKLoginButton class];
    ...
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I guess you can _accept_ your answer to indicate to others in the future.

Comment: How do I add this in Swift?

Comment: @Saty: Just call FBSDKLoginButton() -> will pop a warning ("Result of initializer is unused"), but it works!

Comment: If you say _ = FBSDKLoginButton() you can eliminate the error

Comment: But, this looks like a dirty hack, and does not explain the reason of this error. :(

Comment: @IulianOnofrei It is dirty, but is necessary. The compiler needs to know that the library is being used in order to link against it. There are other ways to solve it, but none are really any "cleaner" than this.

Comment: @devios, But why can't it know that the library is used, if I declared it in the Storyboard? It's dumb

Comment: @IulianOnofrei Presumably it's because resolving the class of a view in the storyboard is a runtime operation and is not processed at compile time, therefore the compiler doesn't know that the class is actually being used and doesn't include the class's code in the final binary. All you need to do is make *some* kind of static (compile-time) reference to the class, even if it does nothing, and the compiler will recognize it as being needed.

Comment: I have `FBSDKLoginKit (4.18.0)` via CocoaPods and I'm not needing to reference `FBSDKLoginButton` anymore.

Comment: This doesn't help with the latest FBSDKLoginKit. Any clues? The facebook login button looks transparent and I can't tap it.

Answer (score 1):

For Swift use FBSDKLoginButton.superclass()

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FBSDKLoginButton.superclass()

    return true
}
```